# django-filter custom filter not get queryset

Tags: python, django, django-filter

**First of all, I'm beginner in Django-filter if you could offer best solution, I'll be glad to hear it.**

I need to filter QuerySet by ForignKeys' fields. And exactly `author` and `worker`.

### Model.py

```
class Object(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    author = models.ForeignKey('Users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Task(Object):
    priority_choices = (
        ('high', 'Высокий'),
        ('middle', 'Стандартный'),
        ('low', 'Низкий'),
    )

    status_choices = (
        ('open', 'Открыта'),
        ('done', 'Выполнена'),
        ('close', 'Закрыта'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    description = models.TextField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    worker = models.ForeignKey('Users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='worker_set')
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=priority_choices)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=status_choices)
```

### Filters.py

```
class TaskFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    my_tasks = filters.BooleanFilter(
        label="Мои задачи",
        method='my_task_filter',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput()
    )
    tasks_for_me = filters.BooleanFilter(
        label="Задачи для меня",
        method='tasks_for_me_filter',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput()
    )
    commented_tasks = filters.BooleanFilter(
        label="Я комментировал",
        method='commented_tasks_filter',
        widget=forms.CheckboxInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ['my_tasks', 'tasks_for_me', 'commented_tasks']

    def my_task_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        print(1, self, queryset, name, value)
        return queryset.filter(author_id=self.request.user.id)

    def tasks_for_me_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        print(2, self, queryset, name, value)
        return queryset.filter(worker_id=self.request.user.id)

    def commented_tasks_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        print(3, self, queryset, name, value)
        return queryset.filter(comment__author_id=self.request.user.id)
```

According to prints in **filters.py** I get:

```
1 <TaskManager.filters.TaskFilter object at 0x7f87290dea90> <QuerySet [<Task: Task object>, <Task: Task object>, <Task: Task object>]> my_tasks False
2 <TaskManager.filters.TaskFilter object at 0x7f87290dea90> <QuerySet []> tasks_for_me True
3 <TaskManager.filters.TaskFilter object at 0x7f87290dea90> <QuerySet []> commented_tasks False
```

So I have two questions: First of all, why only first custom filter get queryset? Also, how can I make filter with three radio buttons which will be just return need queryset?

Comment: I dont see comment field in Task model. 
Also, can you show the result of `Tasks.objects.all().values('author','worker')`

Comment: @iamkhush, here is result: `<QuerySet [{'author': 1, 'worker': 2}, {'author': 1, 'worker': 2}, {'author': 1, 'worker': 3}]>`

Comments model are empty now, so I skip it. Main problem is that queryset of tasks is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>It is clear from the queryset that 3 tasks have author as 1. This also means that you must be querying from user 1. Hence `my_task_filter` returns 3 results.</del>

<del>For `tasks_for_me_filter` you get 0 results since no worker has id 1.</del>

<del>To fix this, you need to pass the user_id (of the worker you wish to check) to this queryset somehow. Maybe using the request parameter.</del>

Although this is the suggested answer - this doesnt fix the issue. Please look into the comments below for some hints.

Comment: Now, user id is 2. Filter get EMPTY queryset BEFORE filtering. So user id does not matter in this case.

Comment: I agree. It seems to me since queryset is being filtered sequentially. I mean, since first one returned empty, the next ones received empty. Can you try changing the order of fields and then check the output?

Comment: Are you right, so I suppose, I should change the strategy of solving this problem.